# Indenting in text mode

Tags: emacs, indentation

Is there an emacs indentation command in text mode that behaves something like:

- With no prefix arg and no region, indent the current line by one space
- With a prefix arg of "n" and no region, indent the current line by "n" spaces
- With no prefix arg and a region, indent the region by one space
- With a prefix arg of "n" and a region, indent the region by "n" spaces

I had thought that "indent-rigidly" did that, but now I find it does something quite different.  And I can't find such a command in the emacs documentation.

Also, I'm curious: did "indent-rigidly" ever behave as I described?

Answer (score 1):

Ah.  I see that the behavior I expected is more-or-less pre-emacs 24.4 behavior.  I guess I need to update emacs more frequently.